# псевдоклас child

Tags: html, css

применяю псевдоклас child, почему-то значения цвет не применяется: 
html

```
<nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Личный кабинет</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Раздел 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Раздел 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Раздел 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Раздел 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Раздел 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

css

```
.navigation a:first-child {
    color: #7e42be;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.navigation a:nth-child(2) {
    color: #70a886;
}
.navigation a:nth-child(3) {
    color: #4f95e5;
}
.navigation a:nth-child(4) {
    color: #f1aa74;
}
.navigation a:nth-child(5) {
    color: #9b8683;
}
.navigation a:nth-child(6) {
    color: #d17789;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.navigation ul li:first-child a {
    color: #7e42be;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(2) a {
    color: #70a886;
}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(3) a {
    color: #4f95e5;
}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(4)  {
    color: #f1aa74;
}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(5)  {
    color: #9b8683;
}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(6) a {
    color: #d17789;
}
```